# Mongodb aggregate lookup condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I want to set a where condition on joined record while fetching all records. I implemented lots of solution on $lookup but didn't get proper solution. Here is my nodejs code. Hope

**Post Model Schema**

```
const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    post_title: String,
    post_location: { type: mongoose.ObjectId, ref: "locations" },
});
```

**Location Model Schema**

```
const locationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    location_name: String,
    address: String,
});
```

**Controller Code**

```
var dataQuery = Posts.aggregate();
dataQuery.lookup({ from: 'locations', localField: 'post_location', foreignField: '_id', as: 'post_location' });
dataQuery.unwind("post_location");
dataQuery.exec().then(postsData => {

});
```

**Output**

```
[{
    "_id": "5e8f179e2bd9f824fce3efd2",
    "post_title": "Post title 1"
    "post_location": {
        "_id": "5e8ee8ae2bd9f824fce3e621",
        "location_name": "Shimla",
        "address": "Shimla, Himachal Pradesh, India",
    },
}
{
    "_id": "5e8f179e2bd9f824fce3efd2",
    "post_title": "Post title 2"
    "post_location": {
        "_id": "5e8ee8ae2bd9f824fce3e621",
        "location_name": "Goa",
        "address": "Goa, India",
    },
}]
```

I want to serach by location_name or, address. But didn't get a proper code to implement. Please help me?

Comment: So `$lookup` is working fine, what do you mean by : *I want to serach by location_name or, address.* ? What is the input & required o/p ?

Comment: @whoami I want to implement some logic in my controller code so I can search by location_name or address from Output which is getting by current controller code.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you wanted to search for & what is the o/p that you're looking for that way it would be easy to provide an answer (There can be multiple ways of search) !!

Comment: Please see my controller code in above query and the current output is there according to models. Right now I just want to filter by location_name or address fields using a $lookup query or some thing else I dont know in the above aggregate() query. So what I do know? I'm expecating an array of a single object with location_name "Shimla" as result.

Comment: Just add this after `unwind` :: `dataQuery.match({$or : [{'post_location.location_name': new RegExp('Shimla', 'i')}, {'post_location.address': new RegExp('Shimla', 'i')}]})`

Comment: @whoami Hey dear... A big thank you from my side. This code worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you've to do is to add [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) stage to aggregation after your `unwind` stage as like below :

**Node.js code :**

```
dataQuery.match({
  $or: [
    { "post_location.location_name": new RegExp("Shimla", "i") },
    { "post_location.address": new RegExp("Shimla", "i") }
  ]
});
```

**DB Query :**

```
{
 $match : {
      $or: [
        { "post_location.location_name": /Shimla/i) },
        { "post_location.address": /Shimla/i }
      ]
    }
}
```

Here we're checking a word `Shimla` to be available in either `location_name` or `address` fields of `post_location` object & retrieving only those documents which match this criteria. As we're using regex we've included `i` to be case-insensitive this is optional.